# Load section of config file into dictionary in net 5.0

Tags: .net-5, configuration-files

I have to work on an application in net 5.0 not developed by me, that I don't know.

I would like to add a section in the config file and load it into a dictionary.

this is the section in config file:

```
{
  "MyApp": {
    "ServiceExceptions": [
        { "Key1": "Value1" },
        { "Key2": "Value2" }
    ]
  }
}
```

this code load the configuration:

```
public static IConfiguration GetConfiguration(string name)
{
    IConfiguration oConfiguration = null;
    string basePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(SharedHelper).Assembly.Location);
    string configPath = Path.Combine(basePath, "Config");

    string fileConfig = string.Format("{0}.{1}.json", name, Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT"));

    oConfiguration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                           .SetBasePath(configPath)
                           .AddJsonFile(fileConfig, optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                           .Build();
        return oConfiguration;
    }
```

this is the code to load to bind the dictionary, but myExceptions is null:

```
_Configuration = GetConfiguration("BD.Authentication.DWA");
Dictionary<string, string> myExceptions = null;
_Configuration.GetSection("MyApp:ServiceExceptions").Bind(myExceptions);
Debug.WriteLine(myExceptions.Count); // throws exception null reference
```

somewhere are loaded the data, but i dont know how to pull out[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move the config file in:

```
{
  "MyApp": {
    "ServiceExceptions": 
        { "Key1": "Value1" },
        { "Key2": "Value2" }
  }
}
```

and retrive the values:

```
var serviceTypeExceptions = _Configuration.GetSection("MyApp:ServiceExceptions").Get<Dictionary<string, string>>();
```